# Chrome Debug doesn't list the connected devices in mac

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, usb-debugging

I recently updated the Chrome to 77.0.3865.90 in MAC and also I have Pixel 3 with chrome 77.0.3865.92 when i try to debug my website using chrome inspect the device is not being listed.

Tried alternate cables and restarting both the devices

Comment: If it worked in older Chrome then it could be a bug in Chrome, see https://crbug.com.

Comment: Even I thought the same at first, when I tried in friends system it worked like charm. Moreover I didn't get the RSA fingerprint to allow usb debugging.

Comment: It's due to the bug in the chrome release and they fixed it in the next minor version